# Why can I import module bs4 or requests from python IDLE shell but not from the python interpreter?

Tags: python, import, module

I can import module BeautifulSoup or requests without any problem when I run it from my script or do it directly in the python IDLE shell:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import bs4
>>> bs4
<module 'bs4' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.pyc'>
>>> import requests
>>> requests
<module 'requests' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.pyc'>
```

However, when I do it from the command prompt using the python interpreter I run into the following errors:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/A/C $ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30,     in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py",         line 4, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pdb import set_trace
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 9, in <module>
    import cmd
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cmd.py", line 53, in <module>
    IDENTCHARS = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_'
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ascii_letters'
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .packages.ssl_match_hostname import CertificateError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/packages/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ssl import CertificateError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 90, in <module>
    import textwrap
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 40, in <module>
    class TextWrapper:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 82, in TextWrapper
    whitespace_trans = string.maketrans(_whitespace, ' ' * len(_whitespace))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

I read a lot of forums, but didn't really understood what could be causing this, and most importantly, how to solve it.

Many thanks for your help,
Best,
Mathieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really IDLE vs. Python shell on console but where the current working directory for the process is.  Because in the directory from wich you start the console Python shell there is a `string.py` which ”shadows” the `string` module from the standard library.  Delete that `string.py` (and the `string.pyc` if it exists) from that folder and other modules will find the standard `string` module again.

Comment: Spot on BlackJack. Thanks a lot for the answer! I will pay attention to how I name my scripts from now on...